# Select выбор списка под категорий

Tags: html, вёрстка, select

В форме есть три `<select>`.
В 1-м списке категории (объявление и услуги), в 2-ом и 3-тем `<select>` список под категорий.

Вопрос: как можно сделать, чтобы при выборе, в первом `<select>` выходил снизу автоматически список под категорий?

Answer (score 1):

на select вешаете обработчик, который проверяет выбранное значение - если оно outher, то делается видимым заранее созданное и скрытое текстовое поле
субмит формы делаете через javascript-функцию, в которой сначала проверяете состояние текстового поля и, если оно не пустое, присваиваете его значение select`у
Если будет время попробую с кодом

Comment: Буди рад если примером покажете заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function innerReplace()
{
    var replace = {
        "1":"<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option>",
        "2":"<option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option>"
    }

    var sel = document.form.select.value;
    var catselect = document.getElementById("catselect");

    catselect.innerHTML = replace[sel];
}

</script>
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
    <select name="select" onchange="innerReplace()">
        <option value="1">Категория 1</option>
        <option value="2">Категория 2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="catselect">
        <option>Сначала выберите категорию</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Сори за грязность, спешу! Ато с работы не выпустят!)))

Comment: Извините а как можно вывести списки из базы

Answer (score 0):

Для этого надо заюзать метод `click()` к другим селектам. Ведь селекты открываются по клику на них, вот и сымитируйте этот самый клик по нужному объекту "select".